# How to count the number of unique elements from two lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with hundreds of columns, and I need to know the number of unique elements in two columns.
Here's a sample of the data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
'colA_1': ["12.456.", "......7", "..34..7"],
'colA_2': ["1......", "1.....7", "..34..7"],
'ID': ["idx1", "idx1", "idx2"]})
```

What I do is:

1. concatenate the two columns
2. Count the unique elements.

I do it like this:

```
df['colA_1'] = df['colA_1'].apply(list)
df['colA_2'] = df['colA_2'].apply(list)
df['colA'] = df['colA_1'] + df['colA_2']
df['colA'] = df. colA.nunique()
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: @mozway sure, sorry for the omission

Comment: What is an element to you "12.456." or "1", "2", ".", etc. ?

Comment: @mozway "1", "2", etc. is an element because when I use `apply(list)` then `"12.456."` becomes `['1', '2', '.', '4', '5', '6', '.']`

Comment: OK, then I provided a solution. It gives me 8 in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
len(set(df2.filter(like='colA').sum().sum()))
```

output: 8

This merges all the string of both columns for all rows and calculates the unique elements with `set`

##### original answer

To calculate unicity, pandas/python hashes the objects. They need to be immutable, which is not the case of lists, thus the error. If your column contains only lists you could convert to string and then calculate the number of unique elements:

```
df2.colA.astype(str).nunique()
```

This is not always a perfect solution but this should work in most cases.

Another option is to not convert to list, but to give you better advice we would need to get an example of the data.

Comment: I just did it, but got `1`as result for every line of the dataset. I edited the question so you know what the data looks like

Comment: I wonder if it would be safer to fillna first, just in case there are NaNs. I think the summing will fail in that scenario.

Comment: @merced There are many ways to make it fall, numbers, objects, etc. The description of the problem is that the DataFrame contains strings. If this is not the case, then it's a different problem. *"Premature optimization of the root of all evil"* D. Knuth ;)